# Access denied on registry entry while debugging in VS2003 on Windows 7

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, iis, windows-7

I have to support an application that was written in **.NET 1.1** many years ago.  I inherited this application. **No, I cannot yet upgrade to a later version of .NET and yes I am aware that it is no longer supported in Windows 7.** It is a has been a huge struggle and just when I get one issue sorted out then the next one pops up.

After a long struggle I managed to get it to run by working through this article:

http://blogs.iis.net/brian-murphy-booth/archive/2007/03/09/how-to-setup-asp-net-v1-1-visual-studio-net-2003-projects-on-iis7-vista.aspx

I also got the debugging to work.  I am running Visual Studio 2003 as an administrator.

In the application it gets the connection string of the database from registry.  I am still debugging/running it locally.  But I am getting an access denied when trying to read the registry key.  I had a look in the registry and the keys do exist.

It fails here and I'm not sure what the issue is:

```
RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(Constants.DBRegKey);
```

Constants.DBRegKey has this value: `"Software\\MyCompany\\MyProject\\Database"`

Is this another Visual Studio 2003 and Windows 7 issue?  Or does this happen in general with all Visual Studio versions?

Comment: The link mentions IIS.. is thsi an app, or, a web page? If so, the web user has very limited rights. You may need to make sure the web user has rights to that section

Comment: 32 bit.  How do I then add rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following in the web.config:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="username" password="password"/>
```

This works, I can read the value of a registry key.  Not sure why this works but it works.  Hope it is the last project that I have to support on `.NET 1.1`.

Although I might mark this as the answer, please I would still like to here more opinions.